# How to get more unique numbers from Random object

Tags: c#

I want to spoof a string by inserting a `-` char. I've made class:

```
static class Spoofer {
    private static char spoofChar = '-';
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static double SpoofPercentage = 0.3;

    public static string Spoof(string input) {
        if (input.Length == 0)
            return "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
            while (rnd.NextDouble() <= SpoofPercentage) {
                sb.Append(spoofChar);
            }
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And this is how I use spoofing:

```
string messageToSpoof = "This is my example message";
string spoofedMessage = Spoofer.Spoof(messageToSpoof);
```

That is how spoofed messages looks like:

```
-Th-is is my- e--x-am--p--l-e messa-g-e
--T-his is --my --exampl--e me--s-sage
This --is my exam--p-le mes-sage
This- -i-s m-y-- example-- ---mess---a---ge
Th-is is my example -message
Th-i----s is m-y- exam-p-le -message
This is-- -my examp--l--e me-ssa-g-e
This -is --my- e-xa--mple m----ess-age
T-his -is--- my- exa-m-ple me---s-s-ag-e
```

So as you can see `-` are not really inserted randomly. It is easy to observe a pattern. In most cases `-` are placed few times. How can I avoid that? I think the problem is, that `Random` object is generating similar values.

Comment: What pattern are you observing?

Comment: I don't think there's a pattern so much as your algorithm will result in a fairly limited number dashes in any given string. `Random` has its problems, but I don't think you are hitting one now.

Comment: `-` are in groups. Its not a random insert.

Comment: Yeah.. your algorithm allows for that with the `while` loop...

Comment: change `while` to `if` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

They look pretty random to me.

It sounds like you are facing the same problem Apple once did with its song shuffle feature. When people see a random clusters of information we naturally superimpose a pattern (which doesn't necessarily exist). This is us projecting a state of order onto the chaos.

If you do not what repeating strings of `-`. Add a check into your `Spoofer` class, a `if` instead of an `while` statement. But this will be inherently less random.

Answer (score 0):

The random number generator (for all its faults), returns a value between 0 and 1. Your ceiling for getting a dash is .3 so that you have 3 chances in 10 to get a dash. In some cases, I see spots where you get less than 3 for a span of 10 characters, and others where there are more than that. That's to be expected for random number generation. (Ever rolled dice in a tabletop game?)

If you're getting too many, lower your ceiling. Or, find a different way to generate random numbers.

The random number generator doesn't generate *truly* random numbers. They're pseudo-random at best.